# Deleting all folders/files except for one folder and all root-files

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-2.0

I've had some months away from Powershell so excuse me if this is obvious..

I have a directory containing hundreds of filed and folders, and I would like to delete everything EXCEPT for all files in the root directory and one of the subfolders.

I will be creating a scheduled task to do this once a week.

This is what I have so far:

```
get-childitem -recurse | ?{ $_.psiscontainer } | remove-item
```

but it is quite obvious that I am only deleting folders..

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to keep the contents of the one subfolder or just the subfolder itself? For the former do this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\foo' -Exclude 'subfoldername' |
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

For the latter delete the contents of the subfolder in a second step:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\foo' -Exclude 'subfoldername' |
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
Get-ChildItem 'C:\foo\subfoldername' | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

With PowerShell v3 and newer you can replace the `Where-Object` filter by adding a parameter `-Directory` to `Get-ChildItem`:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\foo' -Exclude 'subfoldername' -Directory |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
get-childitem -exclude SubFolderName -recurse | ?{ $_.psiscontainer } | remove-item
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will do what you are looking for. From what I have read, the Remove-Item is buggy.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Temp -Recurse | Remove-Item -Exclude W3SVC5 -Recurse -force
```